# Remove punctuation from certain parts of a text file

Tags: r

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
B.1 Blah blah blah
Random sentence.
B.2 Blah blah blah
Random sentence.
```

I want to obtain the output:

```
B1 Blah blah blah
Random sentence.
B2 Blah blah blah
Random sentence.
```

I'm not sure how to remove the specific periods in B.1 and B.2. I do not want to remove any other periods. I was wondering how I would do so. Thank you.

Comment: Is the idea that you'll have strings starting with a letter, then a period, then a number, and you want to remove that period? Or might there be cases where a period occurs somewhere else besides the end of the line that you'll want to remove / not remove?

Comment: There also may be cases where a period occurs somewhere else besides the end of the line that I want to remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lines <- c('B.1 Blah blah blah', 'Random sentence.', 'B.2 Blah blah blah', 'Random sentence.')
```

The initial (most-literal) solution would be to look for a following number:

```
gsub("\\.([0-9])", "\\1", lines)
# [1] "B1 Blah blah blah" "Random sentence."  "B2 Blah blah blah" "Random sentence."
```

If it's the *lack of a space* (or end-of-line) that is important, then

```
gsub("\\.(\\S)", "\\1", lines)
# [1] "B1 Blah blah blah" "Random sentence."  "B2 Blah blah blah" "Random sentence."
```

where `\\S` means the negation of white-space. (See [`?regex`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html)` for more.)

This will fail, of course, if there is a legitimate decimal number (and your locale uses the period for decimal notation):

```
lines <- c('B.1 Blah blah blah', 'Random sentence.', 'B.2 Blah blah blah', 'Random sentence.', 'pi is 3.14')
gsub("\\.(\\S)", "\\1", lines)
# [1] "B1 Blah blah blah" "Random sentence."  "B2 Blah blah blah" "Random sentence."  "pi is 314"
```

The fix is a little more of a regex:

```
gsub("([^0-9])\\.(\\S)", "\\1\\2", lines)
# [1] "B1 Blah blah blah" "Random sentence."  "B2 Blah blah blah" "Random sentence."  "pi is 3.14"
```

though this now will not catch a leading-dot:

```
lines <- c('B.1 Blah blah blah', 'Random sentence.', 'B.2 Blah blah blah', 'Random sentence.',
           'pi is 3.14', '.leading dots are bad.')
gsub("([^0-9])\\.(\\S)", "\\1\\2", lines)
# [1] "B1 Blah blah blah"      "Random sentence."       "B2 Blah blah blah"      "Random sentence."      
# [5] "pi is 3.14"             ".leading dots are bad."
```

So we make things just a little more complicated to catch that.

```
gsub("(^|[^0-9])\\.(\\S)", "\\1\\2", lines)
# [1] "B1 Blah blah blah"     "Random sentence."      "B2 Blah blah blah"     "Random sentence."      "pi is 3.14"           
# [6] "leading dots are bad."
```

which is about as complicated as I want to get here, for fear of [XKCD/1171 Perl Problems](https://xkcd.com/1171/).

Answer (score 1):

Although, `@r2evans` has covered almost all ways, still thought to add an option which will check if a `.` follows `alpha-bates` and then followed by `digits` then only remove that `.`.

```
#Data
lines <- c("B.1 Blah blah blah", "Random sentence.", 
                       "B.2 Blah blah blah", "Random sentence.")

gsub("(.*[[:alpha:]]+)[.]([[:digit:]]+.*)","\\1\\2",lines)

#[1] "B1 Blah blah blah" "Random sentence."  "B2 Blah blah blah" "Random sentence."
```

**Regex Explanation:**

> ```
> (.*[[:alpha:]]+)   : Group 1 for place holder. Anything that follows a alpha-bate
> [.]                : .
> ([[:digit:]]+.*)   : At least a digit and then anything that follows it
> ```